# Gutenberg remove Most Used group

Tags: block-editor

I was searching for a solution to remove the "Most Used" group of blocks from Gutenberg editor and couldn't find any, is there any way?

[image]

Comment: NOTE:  If you hide this your search will not work.  If you notice, when you search for a block the results show up in the Most Used category.  I find this Most Used category very annoying.

Comment: Feel free to post your thoughts here, https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/19070

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS to wp-admin:

**functions.php:**

```
function admin_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-edits', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/admin.css');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_scripts');
```

**admin.css:**

```
#block-editor-inserter__search-1:placeholder-shown + .editor-inserter__results .components-panel__body:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the reply of **Benjamin** and applied CSS but it is not working since WordPress 5.4 so here is the updated CSS which will work in all the versions before 5.4 and 5.4 also.

```
input[id^="block-editor-inserter__search-"]:placeholder-shown+.block-editor-inserter__results .components-panel__body:first-of-type{display:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If the non-programming way is enough, as of WP 5.5, you can easily do it like this:

1. Just open `More tools & options` *(this 3 dots)*

> [image]

2. Open `Options`

> [image]

3. Then uncheck `Enable the Most Used Blocks category in the block library`

> [image]